# Replacing shared object (.so file) while main program is running

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I have a shared object gateway.so (in Linux/C). And  a.out application is using it.

### QUESTION A

I guess: when process a.out starts, the loader loads the gateway.so  (I am not using dl functions like `dlopen`). So all the runtime symbol resolutions to gateway.so will happen in memory. It need not to access gateway.so from disk any more.

Am I right?

So I cannot replace the gateway.so with an updated version, while a.out is running, right?

### QUESTION B

Another related question: Once when I substitued and outdated version of the gateway.so file, i got the message

> "a.out: can't resolve symbol 'Test_OpenGateway'"

Which program component (loader/linker ...) sends this output ? This component is executing as part of the same process context ?

Comment: @all answerer, if possible then please provide some proof of your answer in this case...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the file may still need to be read from disk once the runtime linker (`ld.so`) has mapped it into the process' address space. The way this mapping happens is through the `mmap(2)` system call and the flag `PROT_EXEC` to allow execution.

The map doesn't put the entire file into memory once it is mapped, but actually creates a memory region which would invoke a page fault on-demand if the requested piece of memory isn't already copied, and that page fault is handled in kernel-space by reading at the appropriate offset in the file.

Regarding the second question, it is the runtime linker (`ld.so`) that complains about this. The code that loads `ld.so` is emited as program startup code by the compile-time linker (`ld`), so it is executed in user-space, before `main` is called.

Comment: if possible then please provide some proof/documation of this topic

Comment: The best proof should be to try to delete the `gateway.so` file while the program is executing. Since it is `mmap`-ped, the kernel should have locked it and shouldn't allow deletion.

Comment: I am able to remove gateway.so when main program is running and a.out continue to run without issues. But next time I start a.out I am getting error "can't load library"

Comment: (Above comment : By the term "remove gateway.so" , I in fact renamed gateway.so . Not deleted)

Comment: This could be a "lucky" case, if the kernel has decided that all the `mmap`-ped regions are short and could be directly put into memory, it can safely unlock the file, but in principle, the idea behind `mmap(2)` is to implement *demand paging*.

Comment: See how the [`unlink(2)`](http://landru.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=2&topic=unlink) syscall may fail: *When all links to a file are removed and no process has the file open or **mapped**, all resources associated with the file are reclaimed, and the file is no longer accessible.*

Comment: (I tried rename the .so file manually from shell while app is running. I did not use unlink).By the way gateway.so is a dummy test application. I created that since I have another bigger application which crashed when I replaced the shared library while runtime. So now I got why. Thanks Blagovest Buyukliev.

Comment: That "lucky" case does not exist on modern systems (with coherent buffer cache). The memory pages placed into a process's address space with `mmap(2)` and the disk cache are the same, so `write(2)` operations to the file are reflected into the mapped memory immediately. However, once a page has private changes (possible if `PROT_WRITE` and `MAP_PRIVATE` are both used), any further changes to the file do not affect it.

Comment: Nitpick: with ELF, the fact that `ld.so` is needed is noted in a header and the kernel loads it and passes control to it. With the older a.out format, at least on FreeBSD 2.x/3.x, `ld.so` was brought in like you describe. The effect is pretty much the same.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev:  If you really wanted to replace gateway.so while a programming linking against it is running, can you work around this issue using a symlink?  I.e. make gateway.so a symlink to gateway.so.1.  Then, after starting a.out, change the symlink to point to gateway.so.2?   My theory here is that maybe the linker resolves symlinks to an absolute path leaving you free to muck with the original symlink as you see fit.

Comment: Here's how it works: Files on *nix systems are reference counted. Just because you remove it by name, doesn't remove the file content if any process have the file open. The file is deleted when all processes have closed a descriptor for it. If on the other hand you overwrite the shared library file, the program might later on read data it doesn't expect in that file, and bad things happen.

Answer (score 40):

**Question A**

You can replace the library while an application is using it, if you do it the right way.

Before we get there lets have a look at the main program binary. Here is an example program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void justsit(void) {
  for (;;) {
    sleep(1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("My PID is %d\n", getpid());
  justsit();
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and start it:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o example example.c
$ ./example
My PID is 4339
```

Now it will just sit there, so open a new terminal to do this:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o example-updated example.c
$ cp example-updated example
cp: cannot create regular file `example': Text file busy
```

What happened now? The kernel refused changing file *example* because it has a process that is running that file.

Now lets try to remove it:

```
$ rm example
```

What? That worked? Why can the file be removed, but not replaced? Yes, or rather, the file was not really removed, just the "name", the kernel tells the filesystem to keep the contents of the file. When nothing has the file open any longer the contents are also removed. (*dentry* is removed immediately and but *inode* is freed when it has no users as filesystem people would say)

This can sort of be seen in /proc: (this is why the program prints its PID so you can easily check this)

```
$ readlink /proc/4339/exe
/tmp/t/example (deleted)
```

Anyhow. The fact that it works like this means that one can safely upgrade a program by removing the old binary and putting the new one in same place. There is a program to handle this: install(1).

Ok, back to your question - shared objects.

Let's split the example into two parts, main.c and shared.c:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void justsit(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("My PID is %d\n", getpid());
  justsit();
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
/* shared.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void justsit(void) {
  for (;;) {
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Compile them like this:

```
$ gcc -Wall --shared -o libshared.so shared.c 
$ gcc -Wall -L. -o main main.c -lshared
```

Now hopefully if we try to replace libshared.so we would get a similar "Text file busy" error? Lets see. First start the main program - current directory is not in lib search path so tell dynamic linker to search there:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main 
My PID is 5697
```

Go to a different terminal and replace the library with something obviously broken:

```
$ echo "junk" > libshared.so 
$
```

First - it wasn't refused like replacing the program binary.
And in the other terminal something interesting happened, the program stopped running with the following error message:

```
Segmentation fault
$
```

So it is NOT forbidden to replace a library in use by a program! But as seen from the example above it can have disastrous consequences.

Luckily the same "trick" that was used to replace a running binary can be used to replace a lib in use. Restart the main program (don't forget to recompile libshared.so too as that was replaced by junk) and see how it is safe to do rm on the library. /proc/PID/maps can be inspected to see what shared objects the process is using:

```
$ cat /proc/5733/maps  | grep libshared.so
008a8000-008a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2097292    /tmp/t/libshared.so
008a9000-008aa000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2097292    /tmp/t/libshared.so
008aa000-008ab000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 2097292    /tmp/t/libshared.so
$ rm libshared.so 
$ cat /proc/5733/maps  | grep libshared.so
008a8000-008a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2097292    /tmp/t/libshared.so (deleted)
008a9000-008aa000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2097292    /tmp/t/libshared.so (deleted)
008aa000-008ab000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 2097292    /tmp/t/libshared.so (deleted)
```

The main program continues to run fine. Again this is because just the name (dentry) was removed from disk, not the actual contents (inode). After the removal it is safe to create a new file with the name libshared.so without affecting the running program.

So, to summarize - just use the install command to install programs and binaries.

**Question B**

Yes, that is printed by the dynamic linker, in userspace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    execl("./main", "main", NULL);
    printf("exec failed?\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `gcc -Wall -o execit execit.c`. Remember that `execl` replaces the current process with the specified command.

```
$ ./execit 
main: error while loading shared libraries: libshared.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ rm main
$ ./execit 
exec failed?
```

What happened and what does it tell us? First there is `error while loading shared libraries` without `exec failed?`. No "exec failed" suggests that the process was successfully replaced. This means that the kernel transfered control to the dynamic linker which failed. After "main" was removed it fails early and the process is not replaced.

Comment: I just want to comment that this is a fantastic answer because of the explanation of what is going on behind the screen. But I would like to ask a further clarification: so `rm` unlinks the files from dentry but not inode. At what point is the file removed completely? Is it when the application is stopped (i.e. /proc/<PID>/... is removed)? Or are we starting to use up more space in the filesystem with each `rm` - I am trying to figure out when the file is finally and completely removed. Thanks!

Comment: @code_fodder I think modern Unix filesystems do reference counting. When the process exit, it’s the last reference to the file, so the file is freed.

Comment: The `Text file busy` error is no longer emitted on modern versions of the kernel for some reason.

Comment: I think the reason why a segfault occurred when you replaced the `.so` file is because it has not been loaded yet. If it has been loaded, then changing the file on disk will not affect any process that has already loaded it.

Answer (score 2):

To A:
Yes indeed, once the shared lib is mapped to memory you cannot replace it anymore. It might be even that the system has already loaded a previous version of the lib for some other process and detects that the so is already mapped in to memory and remaps that as the part of the startup process. Thats why you always have to restart (even *nixes) after critical updates ;)

To B:
The symbols the executable uses is recorded in the symbol table within the binary. The system loader scans this table and tries to resolve the addresses of the required function. If it cannot find it, you get this error. So the answer is, the message is produced by the dynamic link loader.

Answer (score 0):

a. Right. In this case, you must work with `dl_*()` stuff and close the file as soon as possible.

b. If you substitute the said file, and it does not contain a required symbol, loading fails and you get the said error.